# How to get into the details view using any primary key from a template to another template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I make a list view and detail view using function..here i get the queryset..I get the query data in list view but I get the query data in list view in template passing pk in url section..

i put `league/<int:pk>/` in path for detail view and in list view template put `{% url 'league-detail' match.pk %}` in href...bt an error occurs :  league() got an unexpected keyword argument `pk`

urls:

```
path('leagues/', views.league, name='league'),
path('league/<int:pk>/', views.league_detail, name='league-detail'),
```

views:

```py
match = Match.objects.all()
```

same for both list view and detail view

templates:

```
{% url 'league-detail' match.pk %}
```

but error is:

```
league() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

i need to go to the `league-detail` template by get actual data using queryset

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t quite follow your question but the reason behind getting an unexpected argument error is mostly that you’re trying to pass ‘match.pk’ in the url without defining it in the urls file

So it could be like:

```
path('league/<int:pk>', views.league_detail, name='league-detail')
```

And then in league_detail function,

```
def league_detail(pk):
     // code goes here
```

Also I’m not sure of this but after doing this you’ll probably need to pass pk in the template like this:

```
{% url 'league-detail' pk=match.pk %}
```

Comment: it's working but the query data is not work properly for each primary key query...i get all the query data but i need to get the query data of specific primary key..
btw thank you for answering me...@rojagtap

Comment: Regarding the data for a particular primary key, you could use something like match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk). Note that it will raise a 404 not found error if the object with the given primary key is not present in the database.

Comment: yeah... but this object is not iterable.....i need to iterate the data...how it is possible? @rojagtap

Comment: Well, I don’t think get_object_or_404 returns a query set to iterate, I mean it’s just a plain object whose pk is equal to the pk you asked for

Comment: but this models class have many field and also have many to many field data,,,that's why need to iterate it @rojagtap

Comment: model.field_name :) and for many to many relationships you can refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I can't help you; the error message clearly states the problem is with the definition of the league_detail view, but you have not posted that